# A word that means "a solution in search of a problem"

Tags: single-word-requests

People tend to let capability mislead priority.  We refer to this as "a solution in search of a problem".  If your job is to point these out to people, it would be nice to do so with a single word.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there IS NO single-word, for that idiom.  As WBT pointed out, "a hammer in search of a nail" is a similar idiom.

Comment: What's wrong with more than one word?

Comment: It's such a useful concept, it just seems like something that should have its own word.  


Do any other languages have a word for this?

Comment: I think 'solution in search of a problem' is probably the best phrase to use. It's well recognised.

Answer (score 5):

I usually refer to (and hear others refer to) such solutions as a *hammer* in reference to [Maslow's Hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) and various [sayings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail) to the effect of, "if you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail."  (Meaning: One who has some tool or solution will tend to see problems as those that can be addressed by that tool/solution, even if that really isn't the right one for that problem.)

Effective use of the term requires the recipient to be already familiar with the concept/proverb, and a context where it's clear that you're not referring to any literal hammer.

Answer (score 0):

Google defines the adjective [**opportunistic**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=opportunistic+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=opportunistic+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.11.9659740...........0.RLpSNnrjyxI&gws_rd=ssl) as exploiting chances offered by immediate circumstances without reference to a general plan or moral principle.

While the Free Dictionary describes one who behaves in such a way as an [**opportunist**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/opportunist) defined as a person who takes advantage of any opportunity to achieve an end, often with no regard for principles or consequences.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a single word meaning a 'solution in search of a problem'.

You might, however, say that the process is **counter-intuitive**, or contrary to intuition or to common-sense expectation.

*Source*: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/counter-intuitive)

Answer (score 0):

How about “hammerheading” like a hungry shark on a relentless solution hunt.

MW gives the adjective, but nary a verb.

> hammerheaded adjective
> 1 : having a head shaped like that of a hammer
> 2 : DENSE, STUPID, THICKHEADED

UD relates it to drug use, heroin.

Comment: Has anyone ever used this term to mean "a solution in search of a problem"?

Answer (score 0):

Such solutions are sometimes known as **chindōgu** or **chindogu**, from the Japanese for "weird tool". There is a Wikipedia page on [chindōgu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chind%C5%8Dgu), which defines it as "the practice of inventing ingenious everyday gadgets that seem to be ideal solutions to particular problems, but which may cause more problems than they solve".

The typical chindogu is a weird product that claims to fulfil a need, but either the need is something unlikely or obscure, or the product is in other ways impractical. Wikipedia gives examples including:

> A combined household duster and cocktail-shaker, for the housewife who wants to reward herself as she is going along.
> The all-day tissue dispenser, which is a toilet roll fixed on top of a hat, for hay fever sufferers.
> The baby mop, an outfit worn by babies, so that as they crawl around, the floor is cleaned.

The whole concept and word are a bit whimsical, so may not be suited for all contexts. In a more serious context the phrase "a solution in search of a problem" is probably better, but in a more whimsical situation you could accuse someone of *practicing chindogu*.